# How to send Mail Using SMTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

So far I have this CODE for email validation and a Mail to send Using SMTPClient However it won't work ,it won't send to the gmail stated. But i think there is no problem with my code. I need some help to make a way for sending Mail .

```
string validEmailPattern = @"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|"
      + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)"
      + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$";
            Regex ex = new Regex(validEmailPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (ex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text))
            {

                MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
                m.From = new MailAddress("kennethmontealto91@gmail.com");
                m.To.Add(new MailAddress("kennethmontealto91@gmail.com"));
                m.Subject = "Try";
                m.Body = "TEST";

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
                {
                    UserName = "kennethmontealto91@gmail.com",
                    Password = "********"
                };
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(m);
```

Comment: have you tried sending the email from others like hotmail or yahoo? you might need to allow access to your google account to be able to send me through gmail.

Comment: wow, your question helped me a lot. Nice and Easy.

Comment: @SaqibMobeen welcome ;) happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your `smtp.Host = "yourdomainname.com";`

Comment: Test@Domain.com means Test@gmail.com?

Comment: no Test@YourDomainname.com first create webmail in your domain account

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code after  **smtp.EnableSsl = true;**

string validEmailPattern = @"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|"
  + @"([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)"
  + @"@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$";
        Regex ex = new Regex(validEmailPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (ex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "kennethmontealto91@gmail.com",
                Password = "********"
            };
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            m.From = new MailAddress("kennethmontealto91@gmail.com");
            m.To.Add(new MailAddress("kennethmontealto91@gmail.com"));
            m.Subject = "Try";
            m.Body = "TEST";

            smtp.Send(m);
        }
```