# How to send mail using SMTP. Yii framework?

Tags: php, email, yii, smtp

I'm trying to send a mail from my server using SMTP. All goes well, but mail is not sent. 
I dont no how, but it wont take `$to` value.

Here is my function code :

```
public function sendEmail($to='',$from='',$subject='',$body='' , $record_id='')
    {                
        $from1=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('global_admin_sender_email');
        if (!empty($from1)){
            $from=$from1;
        }       

        $email_dsiabled_auto_break=getOptionA('email_dsiabled_auto_break');
        if($email_dsiabled_auto_break!=1){
           $body=nl2br($body);
        }

        $send_status=false; $send_msg='';

        $email_provider=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('email_provider');
        //dump($email_provider);
        switch ($email_provider) {
            case "smtp":
                $smtp_host=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_host');
                $smtp_port=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_port');
                $smtp_username=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_username');
                $smtp_password=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_password');

                $mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;

                Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Host=$smtp_host;
                Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Username=$smtp_username;
                Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Password=$smtp_password;
                Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Port=$smtp_port;

                $mail->SetFrom($from, '');
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);
                $mail->AddAddress($to, "");
                if($mail->Send()) {                 
                    $mail->ClearAddresses();    
                    $send_msg=t("error occurred");              
                } else {                    
                    $mail->ClearAddresses();
                    $send_status=true;
                    $send_msg="sent";
                }                       
                break;
```

Here is my View code :

```
<div class="uk-form-row">
      <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","SMTP port")?></label>  
      <?php 
      echo CHtml::textField('smtp_port',
      Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_port'),
      array(
        'class'=>"uk-form-width-large"    
      ))
      ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="uk-form-row">
      <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Username")?></label>  
      <?php 
      echo CHtml::textField('smtp_username',
      Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_username'),
      array(
        'class'=>"uk-form-width-large"    
      ))
      ?> 
    </div>

    <div class="uk-form-row">
      <label class="uk-form-label"><?php echo Yii::t("default","Password")?></label>  
      <?php 
      echo CHtml::textField('smtp_password',
      Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_password'),
      array(
        'class'=>"uk-form-width-large"    
      ))
      ?> 
    </div>

    <p class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small"><?php echo t("Note: When using SMTP make sure the port number is open in your server")?>.<br/>
    <?php echo t("You can ask your hosting to open this for you")?>.
    </p>

    </li>
```

I referred some questions :
[How to send Mail Using SMTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644159/how-to-send-mail-using-smtp)

I didn't get what is the error. Any kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You fires an error when `$mail->Send()` is completed successfully and sets `$send_status=true;` otherwise.

Try to revert it

```
if($mail->Send()) {  
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $send_status=true;
    $send_msg="sent";
} else {                    
    $mail->ClearAddresses();    
    $send_msg=t("error occurred"); 
}
```

And please refer to the official docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html

Comment: Thanks for help. Problem solved. You provided link is for Yii2 and I'm using Yii 1.1.